Aquarite Chlorine Generator
Had our pool guy install aquarite chlorine generator. It would not power on and he stated it was a bad unit. We got a new one and installed it. The same thing is happening. What we witnessed is when the pool is off the power to the aquarite comes on. When we turn the pool on it goes off. Not even the LED is lit. Pool guy is not responding of course. We see that he has both wires going to the timer and nothing directly to the pump. Is that what’s causing this? How do we fix it?

This is almost certainly wired incorrectly. Chlorine generators need to only run when the circulation pump is running, so they should typically be connected in parallel to the pump. If your pool tech isn't responding, it might be time to find another pool tech or an electrician, or to reach out to tech support for the manufacturer.

A guess would be the wiring is insufficient to power both -- the pool pump draws so much current that the chlorinator cannot run.
This might indicate a possible fire or shock hazard. (The possibility of shock because too much current through the neutral wire would raise it above ground.) Too low voltage for the pool motor could also damage it.
Check the voltage across the motor while it is running. If it is less than 110 VAC on 120 VAC mains, or 220 VAC on 240 VAC mains, likely the wiring is insufficient.

This certainly is a guess. There isn't really a mechanism in place to have this happen in a self-resetting way.
